# How to update typings.json and typing files?

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript-typings

My **typings.json** is like this:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "registry:dt/aws-sdk#0.0.0+20160606153210"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "registry:npm/lodash#4.0.0+20160416211519"
  }
}
```

Right now when I want to update, I need run all `typings install XXX --save` again.

Any other way to update **typings.json** and **typing files**?

Is there something like `typings update`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TypeScript 2.x solves the issue. TypeScript 2.x installs typings through `npm`, for example:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

So now the typings files are all in **package.json** with version like below, instead of **typings.json**.

```
"@types/node": "4.0.30"
```

Now you can update your typings like other npm packages.

Comment: and install with yarn?

Answer (score 0):

There is no typings update, but `typings install XXX --save` should do the job